# How to query laravel collection result

Tags: php, sql, laravel, collections, redis

I get data-results from a stored procedureas Laravel collection.

Data is like SQL table. Same keys (column names) inside the object of collection.

Is there a way to query (raw SQL query) this collection and get the final result data I want?

I looked into the [Laravel collection documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections) and I can run some methods to query the collection, but that is not raw SQL query(I need to run little complex raw SQL query on collection data.)

1. Ideally, I need to create a temporary SQL table from the collection data. The collection can be different based on the result and need to create temp table based on that.
2. I also looked into `Redis server` where I store my collection temporary and make a query, but don't find anything that I can store as SQL table and run SQL query on it.
3. The third option would be storing the result data on `Web SQL` and run query but also required to download excel that is being done from the back end.

Did anyone run into the similar issue? Maybe there is something else I can use for this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to query with models like so:

```
//Query the db, and fetch collection with get()
$userCollection = User
    ::where('function_id', 3)
    ->get();
//Query the collection and fetch the first answer, resulting in a user model
$pietPaulusma = $userCollection
    ->where('firstname', 'Piet')
    ->where('lastname', 'Paulusma')
    ->where('email', 'piet@paulus.ma')
    ->first();
```

Or without models like so:

```
DB::table('users')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))
    ->where('status', '<>', 1)
    ->groupBy('status')
    ->get();
```

If you study [this documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries), you should get far :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: I need to make a bunch of aggregations and operations on result collection. that is easy with raw SQL query on collection if possible. As I mentioned I looked into all methods but need to run raw SQL.  I don't use the other way as I need to retrieve data from the collection.

Comment: Then plain old 'DB::raw('select * from users where id = 1')' should suffice. The whole query can go in there.

Comment: You could combine it with https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/cache, and store your results in cache if you like.

Comment: result collection I get is not same every time. It can be totally different with a different type of data. So how can I create temp. table in cache every time based on the collection data. If that is possible I can do that.

Comment: Do you want to store the data because it is a long-running query(slow), or because it is just alot of data that you do not want to cross the apache<->sql connection over and over?

Comment: I need the result collection and another list of data by querying that collection. I need both.  Getting the first result collection is also long running query. So cannot make another one to get data which is based on already retrieved data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167128/discussion-between-lahar-shah-and-rob-biermann).

Answer (score 0):

you can write raw sql queries with `query builder` class. if you want to retrieve some data you can use `select` method like

```
\DB::select('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ...'); // your complex query
```

you can put the whole raw sql query in this method. also use prepare statements like

```
\DB::select('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = ?', [2])
```

to make sure you prevent sql injections.
read more about raw queries at [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#running-queries)

Comment: #1. I need the result collection data. That I got. #2. I need the second set of data based on #1. Dealing with millions of record and cannot make another complex raw query to retrieve the data again from the database.(One big query already made to get #1.)

Comment: you asked for raw query and I showed you how you can do it. if you want to get collection from this query, you can use `collect()` method. if your question is about specific query, then you should provide some code and tell us exactly what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks for looking into but I asked, how do I make a raw query on collection. (Not on database.) As I mentioned I do use store proc that makes raw query against database to get the collection back. And I need to query that collection to get 2nd set of data. I am sorry if I am not that clear in my question. I will update it and will try to make it more clear. Thanks for feedback.